# How do I add the NPOI library to a .NET Core 1.0 project?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, npoi

I would like to add the NPOI library to my .NET Core project. I want to work with xls and xlsx files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 4 steps to add the NPOI library to a .NET Core project.

1. Add `net451` as a dependency under the frameworks property in the `project.json` file and include a reference to the NPOI library:

   ```
   "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    },
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
         "NPOI": "2.2.1"
      }
     }
   },
   ```
2. In the `project.json` file, add `runtimes` as a top-level property:

   ```
    "runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {},
    "win7-x86": {},
    "osx.10.11-x64": {},
    "ubuntu.14.04-x64": {},
    "centos.7-x64": {},
    "rhel.7.2-x64": {},
    "debian.8-x64": {}
   }
   ```
3. In the `project.json` file, remove the `Microsoft.NETCore.App` property from the top-level property `dependencies`

   ```
   "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "type": "platform"
   },
   ```
4. In the `project.json` file, remove the `netcoreapp1.0` property under the top-level `frameworks` property:

   ```
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
     "imports": [
       "dotnet5.6",
       "portable-net45+win8"
     ]
   },
   ```

Example of complete project.json file:

```
 {
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-MyProjectName-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "MailKit": "1.4.1"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NPOI": "2.2.1"
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {},
    "win7-x86": {},
    "osx.10.11-x64": {},
    "ubuntu.14.04-x64": {},
    "centos.7-x64": {},
    "rhel.7.2-x64": {},
    "debian.8-x64": {}      
  }
}
```

Comment: To be clear here.. you've taken a .NET core app and turned it into a standard asp.net app, correct?  IOW, the .net core functionality has been removed.

Comment: @paqogomez That's correct. When I did this I wanted to use the new .net core app project type. That allowed me to use the DI container and the MVC/ Web API controllers in a single project. Now I believe there is a net standard project that give you all of this. But there wasn't when I did this.

Answer (score 0):

NPOI has been supporting .NET standard since NPOI 2.4.1.