# reference an existing .NET Framework Project in an ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an existing project with .NET framework 4 its a business logic layer

I have created .NET core app with core framework and try to add exist business layer as reference and I 
tried with this example :  [How do I reference a .NET Framework project in a .NET Core project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148128/how-do-i-reference-a-net-framework-project-in-a-net-core-project)

I also created core app with .net framework and try to add reference its also not work

please check the below images and give me help :)

```
---------  .net framework
```

[image]

```
------ core project
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The earliest supported .NET version is 4.5.2. It wouldn't be surprising if the Core team decided not to support an obsolete version - in fact it would make perfect sense

Comment: any idea do  u have ?

Comment: The obvious. Upgrade the project's target framework and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution when u add the reference to .net framework core project you need to click restore packages button :)

and .net core frame work project can not add the .net framework project reference

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to the chart on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library you need to upgrade your libraries to at least version 4.5 of the Framework.

I'm currently using version 4.6 of the Framework for my libraries and referencing them from an Asp.Net Core MVC Web Project without issue.

You may find these links helpful as well:

- Step by step instruction by Scott Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx
- Explaination of Target Framework Monikers: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/