# Creating new project that targets .NET Core using .NET Framework code

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, .net-framework-version

I have a C# class library project (project A) that targets .NET framework v4.5 that I'm currently using as a windows app service. I have this package deployed as a nuget package. I now want to add it's functionality to an AWS lambda function. When I attempt to so that I get an error saying that their frameworks are incompatible (.NET Core/.NET Framework). So the solution I'm planning is to create a new project and upload it to nuget that targets the .NET Core framework and references that same code base as project A.

However, when I create a new project in VS 2015 targeting Class Library (.NET Core) in VS 2015 it creates a project that references .NETStandard V1.6, which prevents me from referencing project A in it. I have .NET Core installed on my machine and I'm able to separately create for example a lambda function that references .NETCoreApp V1.0. I won't have access to VS 2017. How can I create this new project that is compatible with the lambda function?

Comment: See my answer to this question: [Reference a .Net 4.6.2 project in a .NetCore project (VS2017 15.4.4)
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348531/reference-a-net-4-6-2-project-in-a-netcore-project-vs2017-15-4-4/47359253#47359253). Tl;dr: .NET Standard was created for precisely this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly (and I very well may not), then you propose creating a little project B that targets .net core and references project A that targets .net framework 4.x?

That won't work no matter which why you try it, no matter how many dependencies (library wrappers) you insert between the AWS lambda function and project A.  If AWS lambda requires .NET core (I don't know AWS lambda), then you must recompile your project A to target .NET Standard or .NET core.

Comment: Sort of. Rather than project A referencing project B I thought there might be some way that project B could just reference the .cs source files in project A and use them.

Anyway, I've decided to just refactor project A to be .net compatible altogether. I'm going to mark this question as answered and I started a different question to cover that as it's really a different technical question now:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48310854/change-net-project-target-from-net-framework-4-5-to-net-core