# Change .NET project target from .net framework 4.5 to .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-framework-version

I need to change a project to target .net core instead of .net 4.5 (as it's to now be used in a lambda function).

I followed the instructions here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/
And analysed the project for dependencies etc. But there is no instructions on how to actually change the target framework. When I look at the properties of the project it only gives me the option to change the target framework to other versions of the .net framework, not .net core.

I installed .net core from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Comment: "I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and don't have the option to upgrade to VS2017." Then you're basically stuck when it comes to developing in VS, unless you really want to use the preview SDK. Do you have the option to use VS2017 *as well as* VS2015? Do you have the option to develop from a command line, or with VS Code?

Comment: ok, so I just checked and our organisation is now supporting VS2017 (it wasn't last time I checked!), so I'm installing it. I'l modify the question to remove that line about it.

Comment: Well once you've installed VS2017 you should be able to migrate to Core fairly easily.

Comment: So I installed VS2017 but still don't have the option to target .net core in the properties section of the project.

Comment: I suspect you need to go through an explicit migration step - I can't remember how to do it in VS, but from the command line, "dotnet migrate" may be what you're after. I'm sure there *is* a VS option somewhere though.

Comment: Ah, no, I'm wrong: dotnet migrate is for project.json-style projects. Honestly, I'd probably move the existing project file somewhere else and use "dotnet new" to create the new project file, then go from there.

Comment: Exactly, hence my later comment. I suspect creating a new replacement project will be the simplest path - and I'd expect it to be reasonably straightforward in most cases.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Any update on this as available option in the target framework drop down list of project properties?  I still don't see .net core as available option even after installing sdk.

Comment: @swcraft: Do you see it when creating a new project? And with VS2019 rather than VS2017 now?

Comment: @Jon Skeet  Sorry, I didn't provide you more details.  I meant when trying to upgrade target framework existing project.  Creating a new project always showed all the options as navigating style. (1. choose asp.net core web app -> 2. choose which .net core version)

Comment: @swcraft: Right, I suspect it may be as before: migrating via "creating a new project" may well be simpler.