# .net core app target .net framework 4.5.2 on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-4.5, .net-core

I wanted to understand the dot net core support a bit more.
My basic  understanding was that if I wanted to run a .net app on Linux then it needs to be built .net core and targeted netcoreapp1.0 framework to guarantee this.
1) I assume the above assumption is correct?

2) When I was reading various articles online, such as this one about referencing exiting .net framework project within a .net core application (https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx)
If I did this, presumably the app would only run on Windows and not Linux?

3) In the following article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2016/06/28/running-net-core-apps-on-multiple-frameworks-and-what-the-target-framework-monikers-tfms-are-about/
In context to running with .net run 4.5.2 option (
`dotnet run -f NET452`), it's mentioned:

> *If this app were running on the .NET Core Platform, let’s say on a Linux box  or a Mac, this code won’t be executed, but the app would
>   still be running on Linux or MacOS.*

What's the distinction between running and not executing? If my initial understanding was correct, then by running with .net 4.5.2 option on Linux I wouldn't expect the app not to run at all.

Appreciate a few questions there but really wanted to understand  .net core a bit more.

Comment: The quote actually talks about code where the Windows specific part is included in a conditional compilation statement `#if NET452`.

Comment: not every words of a blog post can be fully trusted. With official documentation like this, you don't need to waste too much time, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

Answer (score 10):

There is a difference between `.NET Core` and `ASP.NET Core` and the articles you mentioned are about running `ASP.NET Core` "apps" on `.NET Framework`. Let my try to clarify this using a few declarative statements:

- `.NET Core` is the cross-platform runtime.
- `ASP.NET Core` is a set of libraries that until version 1.1.* can run
  on both `.NET Framework` and `.NET Core`.
- This means you can create a `.NET Framework` application (=> e.g.
  `net452`) and use `ASP.NET Core`in this application.
- The CLI tooling works for both projects targeting `netcoreapp*` and
  `net*` - but `net*` currently only works on windows.

This means that for `netcoreapp1.*`, you cannot reference arbitrary libraries that have been built for .NET Framework. If you change the target framework to say `net452`, you are no longer building a .net core application, but a .net framework application.

For `ASP.NET Core 2.0` this is going to change. Again a few statements:

- `ASP.NET Core 2.0` is still a set of libraries but they can only be used on `.NET Core 2.0` and not on `.NET Framework`

  - Do note that this is still under discussion at the time of writing: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2022
- `.NET Core 2.0` is able to freely reference libraries that have been built for `.NET Framework` up to version `4.6.1`

  - However, some libraries may fail at run time if they try to use API methods that aren't available on `.NET Core`

Comment: This answered 6 questions I had immediately, after plenty of MSDN and Google inquiries. Much thanks! .NET Core for me it is ;)