# How to use .net framework from .net core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I have a .net core xUnit project that references a .net framework project that references Microsoft's Azure Notification Hub API.

It builds, but when try and create a hub, I get the error...

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51

Which seems like an odd error to get given that System.Configuration is referenced.

How do I make the Azure referencing project act like a framework 4.7 project?

Comment: Can you set it to copy local and then do an assembly bind to that version and see if it works? I have no idea why it's not working btw but I'd try this if I were you and see how it goes.

Comment: Version 0 is not a very happy number, hard to imagine what kind of sledgehammer was involved.  In general, the .NETCore runtime cannot load a .NET Framework assembly, you'd have to rebuild the assembly by targeting .NETStandard.  That is not necessarily simple, they did release a core replacement for System.Configuration recently.  As always, the best advice is to wait until they are done.  The proverbial version 3, perhaps.

Comment: What universe am I living in? Are these machines supposed to be putting everyone out of a job in the next couple of decades?

Comment: Related post - [How do I reference a .NET Framework project in a .NET Core project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38148128/465053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft just shipped a new version that's compatible to .NET Standard 2.0,

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-notifications-hubs-net-sdk-now-compatible-with-net-standard-2-0/

Please upgrade your SDK to use that. Of course, you need to make other changes according to their documentation.

Answer (score 4):

If you are targeting .NET Core, make sure you've referenced NuGet package `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`.

See related question: [Is ConfigurationManager.AppSettings available in .NET Core 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591910/is-configurationmanager-appsettings-available-in-net-core-2-0)