# Get connection string from Entity Framework web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have EF connection string in my web.config as shown below

```
  <connectionStrings>    
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Pricing;Integrated Security=False;UID=User;Pwd=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>   
  </connectionStrings>
```

and in my code I am doing this to get just the connection string which I am using for some other controls

```
SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection)Entities.Current.Connection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString;
```

The issue I am facing is that I am getting the connection string but for some reason it does not have the password in it

```
Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Pricing;Integrated Security=False;UID=User;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

and so my connections are failing. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here. I just need the below part

```
Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Pricing;Integrated Security=False;UID=User;Pwd=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Thanks

Edit : So looks like that the password is hidden by design 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a5730be-c93e-4da5-a614-7ed629f06f51/why-would-password-of-connectionstring-be-filtered-after-instantiating-any-object-in-entity?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Not sure if there is any other way

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ConfigurationManager is available in Core ([Is ConfigurationManager.AppSettings available in .NET Core 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591910/is-configurationmanager-appsettings-available-in-net-core-2-0)).

Why not try that? Then pull the connection string and password (stored as separate key under  if need be) out of the web.config.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but that would give me the whole connection string I was just looking for the data source part ..."metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=Source;Initial Catalog=Pricing;Integrated Security=False;UID=User;Pwd=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"