# Console Application throwing a CS1069 Error when trying to use settings. C# .NET5

Tags: c#, .net-5

I have tried googling this issue, and resolving it myself, but sadly no luck.

I have not been wanting to make this as this seems like a very beginner mistake, but I just can't wrap my head around the issue here.

Steps to recreate:

1. Fire up Visual Studio 2019 on Windows and create a C# .NET5 Console App
2. Write some code or don't, add 2 other projects to the solution (both winforms) and build the console app.
3. Add the settings file in the project.
4. Try to build.

`expected result:` app builds no problem, settings are normal.

`actual result:` app doesnt build, `settings.designer.cs` throws the following error

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1069  The type name 'ApplicationSettingsBase' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Configuration'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.   AppName D:\projects\AppName\AppName\AppNameSubBranch\AppNameSubBranch\Settings.Designer.cs  16  N/A

> Debugging information
>
> > Building x86 EXE file with Visual Studio 2019 | .NET5 Console App with no NuGet Packages installed. | Running everything on Windows 10 Home x64.

The error is being thrown at line `16` `ApplicationSettingsBase` and line `18` `global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`

Full settings.designer.cs code:

```
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace AppName{
    
    
    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "16.8.1.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {
        
        private static ShellSettings defaultInstance = ((ShellSettings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new ShellSettings())));
        
        public static ShellSettings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If further information or clarification is needed, please leave a comment.

I want to add aswell that there are no problems in previous console apps and in the winforms projects that I did. It's something with this one that is wrong.

Comment: You may need a reference to System.Configuration

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591910/is-configurationmanager-appsettings-available-in-net-core-2-0