# Constructing a controller with another constructor

Tags: asp.net-core

I am attempting to use IConfigurations to create a connectionstring:

```
public class ShippingRequestController: Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public ShippingRequestController(IConfiguration _configuration)
        {
            Configuration = _configuration;
        }
    }
```

And get the connection string by

```
Configuration.GetConnectionString("ShipRequestDBString")
```

This works well, however I need to create an instance of this controller in a separate controller and I don't know what to use for the **IConfiguration** parameter or if that is even possible.

```
ShippingRequestController mySRControl = new ShippingRequestController(WHAT DO I PUT HERE);
```

Comment: "create an instance of this controller in a separate controller " Do you want to Call a controller from another controller ?  "I don't know what to use for the IConfiguration parameter or if that is even possible." In another controller you can  inject IConfiguration  like your ShippingRequestController. What do you mean ? Could you explain more ?

Comment: I would like this controller to be able to read the connectionstring data from the appsettings.json file but I am not sure what to put in the parameter when it is called by a separate controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer at [Is ConfigurationManager.AppSettings available in .NET Core 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591910/is-configurationmanager-appsettings-available-in-net-core-2-0) from Yusif Karimov

```
namespace DemoWeppApp
{
    public static class StaticConfigurationManager
    {
        public static IConfiguration AppSetting { get; }
        static StaticConfigurationManager()
        {
            AppSetting = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();
        }
    }
}
```

This removes the requirement of a parameter in the constructor.